# How can I check the stack limits, and accomplish Chicken Scheme style recursion in Java?

Tags: java, stack, stack-overflow, chicken-scheme

Consider the following code. This code almost implements Chicken Scheme style recursion where most of the time functions are directly called but occasionally there is a more complicated trampolining procedure. However, the code doesn't quite work correctly. What I really want is a method stackLimitsAlmostReached that returns a boolean value that indicates if there is a danger of a stack overflow. How can I check stack limits, and accomplish Chicken Scheme style recursion in Java?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static abstract class Thunk {
    public abstract Thunk x();

    public final void run() {
        Thunk ip = this;

        while (ip != null)
            ip = ip.x();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] unused) {
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    new Thunk() {
        public Thunk x() {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");

            try {
                return this.x();
            } catch (StackOverflowError t) {
                System.out.println("GC!");
                scanner.nextLine();
                return this;
            }
        }
    }.run();
}
}
```

Comment: So the real question is about checking how much space is left on the stack, and nothing really about recursion or Chicken or Scheme?

Comment: @JimGarrison The question is not related to Chicken Scheme, but I feel that some enthusiasts (and definitely developers who worked on the code for tail recursion) of Chicken Scheme would likely have experience fiddling with stacks in C, and also might have tried to accomplish similar stuff in Java. In particular, I imagine the following conversation might have occured in the far off ungoogleabe corners of the internet. Joe: Why not port Chicken Scheme to Java? Bob: That would be a lot of work and wouldn't make sense. Plus I checked and there's no way to check the stack size at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey i may have misunderstood your question , but i think that you must look first for these options (Java wise , but this is isn't the problem IMO)

```
-ss Stacksize to increase the native stack size or

-oss Stacksize to increase the Java stack size,
```

The default native stack size is 128k, with a minimum value of 1000 bytes. The default java stack size is 400k, with a minimum value of 1000 bytes.

But what i really feel i should warn you about is that the JVM can't support tail call optimisation because of it's security model. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) .
Each time you call the same function , you introduce a new stack frame and that's why
you run on limits fast. A proper scheme that supports TCO doesn't actually create a new
stack frame , it just updates the values and returns to a continuation at the start of the
current frame. this makes recursion very efficient.

Even clojure that runs on the JVM suffers from this problem , that's why it has a lambda
called recur to handle that limitation.
check also : 
[TCO paper](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1333)

Comment: Every time a function calls itself a new stack frame is allocated? That is really bad. So ignoring the stack overflow issue entirely (which is what I wanted to work around in the first place) does that mean a function calling itself is less efficient than using trampolines (like Clojure apparently does?)